# How can I make isearch match phrases across line breaks?

Tags: isearch, whitespace, newlines

Suppose I have a text document (e.g. org-mode, Markdown, etc.) in which I would like to search for the phrase "hello world". Unfortunately, if paragraphs in this document are filled (e.g. *via* `auto-fill-mode`), then there might be a newline between "hello" and "world". **Is there any way I can have isearch treat any whitespace, including line breaks, as equivalent to a single space when searching?** I know I can `isearch-forward-regexp` for `hello[[:space:]]+world`, but that's a little more difficult to remember and awkward to type for something that I'd rather have as the default behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Option `search-whitespace-regexp`:

> `search-whitespace-regexp` is a variable defined in `isearch.el`.
>
> Its value is `"\\s-+"`
>
> Documentation:
>
> If non-`nil`, regular expression to match a sequence of whitespace chars.
>
> When you enter a space or spaces in the incremental search, it
> will match any sequence matched by this regexp.  As an exception,
> spaces are treated normally in regexp incremental search if they
> occur in a regexp construct like `[...]` or `*`, `+` or `?`.
>
> If the value is a string, it applies to both ordinary and
> regexp incremental search.  If the value is `nil`, or
> `isearch-lax-whitespace` is `nil` for ordinary incremental search, or
> `isearch-regexp-lax-whitespace` is `nil` for regexp incremental search,
> then each space you type matches literally, against one space.
>
> **You might want to use something like `"[ \t\r\n]+"` instead.**
>
> In the Customization buffer, that is `[` followed by a space,
> a tab, a carriage return (control-M), a newline, and `]+`.
>
> You can customize this variable.

See the part in **bold**, which tells it to match also newline chars (`\n`).

See also `M-s SPC` (`isearch-toggle-lax-whitespace`) during Isearch:

> `isearch-toggle-lax-whitespace` is an interactive compiled Lisp function
> in `isearch.el`.
>
> `(isearch-toggle-lax-whitespace)`
>
> Toggle lax-whitespace searching on or off.
>
> In ordinary search, toggles the value of the variable
> `isearch-lax-whitespace`.  In regexp search, toggles the
> value of the variable `isearch-regexp-lax-whitespace`.

You can also just search explicitly for a match that allows newline chars: `C-M-s hello[` `SPC` `C-j` `TAB` `]+world`. (Interactively, use `C-j` to insert a newline char.)